# Should I store application-scope variable inside a file in PHP?

Tags: php, session, variables, application-scope

I want store a variable shared between sessions (application-scope):

1. It is not user session-specific (so I can't put it in $_SESSION[]).
2. It is a long term storage (so I can't use APC - Alternative PHP Cache).

So, I use a file do store the variable and access it using file_get_contents and file_put_contents functions.

Is it a good way of proceeding or is there any alternative?

Comment: Would the database not be the prefect place to store this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear your's is a global, server side issue.  I would use a Database to do it.  Just [CRUD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) when needed.

You'rs may do the work, but I recommend the database approach, due to the enhanced capabilities that it provides like logging, checking the history of events.  I think is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use mysql database to store this application-scope variable.